# NP-chunker value error (Python nltk)

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, chunking

I am building an NLP-pipeline based on the Python NLTK book (chapter 7). The first segment of codes correctly preprocesses the data, but I am unable to run its output through my NP-chunker:

```
import nltk, re, pprint

#Import Data

data = 'This is a test sentence to check if preprocessing works' 

#Preprocessing

def preprocess(document):
    sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(document)
    sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sentences] 
    sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sent) for sent in sentences]
    return(sentences)

tagged = preprocess(data)
print(tagged)

#regular expression-based NP chunker

grammar = "NP: {<DT>?<JJ>*<NN>}"
cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar) #chunk parser
chunked = []
for s in tagged:
    chunked.append(cp.parse(tagged))
print(chunked)
```

This is the traceback I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\u0084411\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\u0084411\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/u0084411/Box Sync/Procesmanager DH/Text Mining/Tools/NLP_pipeline.py", line 24, in <module>
    chunked.append(cp.parse(tagged))
  File "C:\Users\u0084411\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\chunk\regexp.py", line 1202, in parse
    chunk_struct = parser.parse(chunk_struct, trace=trace)
  File "C:\Users\u0084411\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\chunk\regexp.py", line 1017, in parse
    chunkstr = ChunkString(chunk_struct)
  File "C:\Users\u0084411\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\chunk\regexp.py", line 95, in __init__
    tags = [self._tag(tok) for tok in self._pieces]
  File "C:\Users\u0084411\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\chunk\regexp.py", line 95, in <listcomp>
    tags = [self._tag(tok) for tok in self._pieces]
  File "C:\Users\u0084411\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\chunk\regexp.py", line 105, in _tag
    raise ValueError('chunk structures must contain tagged '
ValueError: chunk structures must contain tagged tokens or trees
>>>
```

What is my mistake here? 'Tagged' is tokenized, so why does the program not recognize this?

Many thanks! 
Tom

Comment: See [Why am I getting error? ValueError: chunk structures must contain tagged tokens or trees](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269543/why-am-i-getting-error-valueerror-chunk-structures-must-contain-tagged-tokens).

Comment: I have implemented this, but I get the same traceback

Comment: Your `tags` must be a tuple or Tree. See http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/chunk/regexp.html.

Comment: Sorry for this basic question, but is there a way to convert tagged to a tuple or Tree?

Comment: When I convert tagged to a tuple (using (tuple(tagged)) the problem does not go away

Answer (score 3):

You'll slap your forehead when you see this. Instead of this

```
for s in tagged:
    chunked.append(cp.parse(tagged))
```

it should have been this:

```
for s in tagged:
    chunked.append(cp.parse(s))
```

You were getting the error because you were not passing `cp.parse()` a tagged sentence, but a list of them.

Comment: OK, thank you very much, now I get some result, but I am not really sure how to interpret it: [Tree('S', [('THis', 'NNP'), Tree('NP', [('sentence', 'NN')]), ('contains', 'VBZ'), ('one', 'CD'), Tree('NP', [('noun', 'NN')]), Tree('NP', [('phrase', 'NN')])])]

Comment: I am unable to call chunked.draw to get a visual representation; traceback gives me: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'draw'

Comment: You are typing `chunked.draw()`? It's a list (a list _you_ defined), the trees are inside it. Try `chunked[0].draw()`.

Comment: @Tom if this answer solved your problem, please "accept" it by clicking on the big check mark to the left.